# Managing users via SQLAlchemy DB model (updated)

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I am currently in the process of writing a system application that will be operated by multiple users. This will require individual users to access the application while limiting access to those that shouldn't be using it. The application will have several areas of access, which all users will not have access to. At this time, it may change in the future, the application is more or less a proof of concept and will be storing user information in a DB.

What I have here is what I'm calling the Operator Library. This part of my code is strictly how to access the portion of the DB that interacts with the *users* table. There will be other libraries that will be written to access the DB related to specific tables in a very similar manner to the below.

UPDATE:

looking at the documentation, it seems they recommend using a *with* statement for handling opening and using individual sessions. I've also added some simple exception handling.

Anything else I should be adding?

**DBOperatorLibary.py**

```
from Models import Operator, engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

local_session = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)


def create_operator(username, password, privilage):
    ret = None
    with local_session() as session:
        operator = Operator(username=username, privilage=privilage)
        if operator.password == "":
            operator.password = password

        session.add(operator)
        try:
            session.commit()
            session.refresh(operator)
            ret = operator
        except Exception as e:
            ret = e.args

    return ret

def get_operators():
    with local_session() as session:
        operators = session.query(Operator).all()

    return operators

def update_operator(operator_id, username, password, privilage):
    ret = None

    with local_session() as session:
        operator = session.query(Operator).get(operator_id)
        operator.username = username
        operator.password = password
        operator.privilage = privilage
        try:
            session.commit()
            session.refresh(operator)
            ret = operator
        except Exception as e:
            ret = e.args

    return ret

def delete_operator(operator_id):
    ret = None

    with local_session() as session:
        operator = session.query(Operator).get(operator_id)
        session.delete(operator)
        try:
            session.commit()
            ret = operator
        except Exception as e:
            ret = e.args

    return ret

def validate_operator_password(username, password):
    with local_session() as session:
        operator = (
            session.query(Operator)
            .filter(Operator.username == username)
            .first()
        )
        if operator is None:
            return False

    return operator.check_password(password)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ...
```

**Models.py**

```
from BaseModel import Base
from OperatorModel import Operator
from RecordModels import Record
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine("sqlite:///db/application.db", echo=True)

Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)
```

**BaseModel.py**

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase, MappedAsDataclass

class Base(MappedAsDataclass, DeclarativeBase):
    """subclasses will be converted to dataclasses"""
```

**OperatorModel.py**

```
from datetime import datetime

from BaseModel import Base
from sqlalchemy import func
from sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid import hybrid_property
from sqlalchemy.orm import Mapped, mapped_column
from werkzeug.security import check_password_hash, generate_password_hash

class Operator(Base):
    __tablename__ = "operators"

    oid: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, init=False)
    created_on: Mapped[datetime] = mapped_column(
        init=False, server_default=func.now()
    )

    username: Mapped[str]
    privilage: Mapped[str] 

    _password: Mapped[str] = ""

    @hybrid_property
    def password(self):
        return self._password

    @password.setter
    def password(self, password):
        self._password = generate_password_hash(password)

        return self._password

    def check_password(self, password):
        return check_password_hash(self._password, password)

    def __repr__(self):
    return f"User Record {self.oid}\
        \n\tUsername: {self.username} \
        \n\tPrivilage: {self.privilage} \
        \n\tCreated On: {self.created_on}"
```

Comment: I have rolled back Rev 5 → 3. Please see [_What should I do when someone answers my question?_](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `with` looks good.

```
        operator = Operator(username=username, privilage=privilage)
```

nit: Please use conventional spelling of "privilege".

## type stability

```
            ret = operator
        except Exception as e:
            ret = e.args
```

I'm not crazy about the Public API offered by `create_operator`, there.
You have created a "difficult to consume" API;
caller must distinguish between those two cases.
When there's many call sites, at least one of them likely is buggy,
failing to properly test it.

Better to let that exception bubble up the call stack.

This pattern repeats throughout the code base, bloating it up.
Better to `raise` at those other locations, as well.

## enforce a password policy

```
        if operator.password == "":
```

I don't understand this.
How did that row come to appear in the database?
Delete such rows.
Require that operators shall use credentials for access.

## sensible credentials

Please delete that `password` column.
If (when) an attacker compromises your server,
the release of plaintext passwords will cause
catastrophic harm to you, your users, and to *other* sites they use.

Use [argon2id()](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argon2)
to turn each password into a (salted) hash, and store *that*
in a new `credential` column.

## blind query

Consider renaming `get_operators` to `get_all_operators`.
I was a little surprised by the absence of parameter(s) fed to a WHERE clause.

## extra refresh

```
def update_operator...
            ...
            session.refresh(operator)
```

What do we believe the refresh() did there?
Looks like "nothing", to me.

## rename column

```
class Operator(Base):
    ...
    def check_password(self, password):
        return check_password_hash(self._password, password)
```

nit: Please use conventional spelling of "library".

Back in DBOperatorLibary your identifiers were telling me that
we're storing cleartext passwords.
But here we are passing around a
[hash](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/utils/#werkzeug.security.generate_password_hash).
Please use identifiers that tell the truth.

Using pbkdf2 is reasonably good, though
[argon2id](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/issues/1652)
would be better (slower for attackers to brute force it).

Your `@password.setter` uses especially confusing
identifiers, given that same word is used to
represent two radically different concepts.

---

EDIT

## truthful identifiers

Two classic issues in software engineering are

1. "comments lie!", and
2. "identifiers lie!"

No one wants to read a two-sentence `# comment` which
*used* to speak the truth about an algorithm,
back before requirements changed we altered the code
to have brand new behavior.

No one wants to read code like this all-too-typical example:

```
def mean(nums: list[int]) -> float:
    avg = 0  # accummulator, a running sum
    for num in nums:
        avg += num
    avg /= len(nums)
    return avg
```

That variable is clearly in no way an "average" until the very end.
So we can't reason about loop variants in terms of
a mathematical average, we must go through mental gymnastics
to ignore what our eyes are showing us and read that
as "accummulator" or "running sum" within the loop.

Much better to phrase it like this:

```
def mean(nums: list[int]) -> float:
    acc = 0
    for num in nums:
        acc += num
    return acc / len(nums)
```

(Obviously in python we'd prefer `sum(nums) / len(nums)`,
this is just for illustration.)

Interlude: Here is an example password hash. It is 64-bit prefix of SHA-2.

```
$  echo -n secret123 | shasum -a 224 | cut -c1-16
8a73901c428f41be
```

In the OP code, we have several instances where ostensibly
we're passing a `password` around, so it might have a
value like `"secret123"`. Sometimes those identifiers
speak the truth. Often they are *really* holding a hash,
and we might expect `pw_hash` to have a value
like `"8a73901c428f41be"`.

Recommend you rename some of those identifiers.
Future maintenance engineers will thank you.

---

Crypto algorithms often want to see at least 128 bits
of true entropy in key material, in order to make
solid security guarantees.
If you look at passwords memorized by real users,
it appears that often they have trouble remembering
more than about 40 bits of entropy.
(A password like "banana" consumes 48 bits of storage
but has significantly less entropy than that.)

## password stretchers

Why do we use pbkdf2, or the better more-modern argon2id?
To thwart certain attack scenarios.

Imagine that Mallory obtains a credential being sent across
the wire or being stored on-disk on the webserver.
She wants to be able to present valid credentials to
your server and to other servers frequented by your users,
which possibly use the same memorized password.

If passwords are stored in a file as plaintext,
a single webserver breach is catastrophic for you
and for other servers.

If credentials are stored as e.g. SHA-2 or SHA-3 hashes,
Mallory can play dictionary words ("apple") and
generated words ("secret1234") against her own GPU
that computes the hash function, hoping for a match.
Those are designed to be quick hash functions,
so in an hour she can explore quite a large key space.
We call this an "off-line" attack, since Mallory
can conduct the search without contacting your on-line server.

If credentials are stored as argon2id hashes,
she can still launch the same attack,
but it was designed to be an intentionally slow hash function
so she'll be able to explore a much much smaller key space
in the same amount of time.
We have also forced her to purchase significantly more RAM
for her GPU, again due to intentional aspects of the
hash function's design.
The design goals for the (earlier) pbkdf2 function
were similar. Experiences with that nice bit of engineering
informed development of the new and improved argon2 suite
of hash functions.

tl;dr: Use argon2id when {storing, checking} a user's memorized password.

Comment: Finally got around to applying your suggestions. Most of what you suggested I understand. I need to look into what you are talking about regarding passwords and credentials. Including what you mean by "Please use identifies that tell the truth". I will however looking into argon2id. thank you again

Comment: Cool. Ok, I expanded on that topic -- look for "EDIT".